# Product of two arrays

Tags: java, product, multiplication

i'm a beginner at java and i'm trying to create a program that takes two arrays, and multiplies each corresponding number in both arrays and creates a third array that displays the output. I've attempted and keep running into errors.

I've created an additional method that takes the arrays and multiplies them, however i'm not sure if i've created the third array correctly that returns the product.
Any help or insight into how to approach this problem or any corrections is much appreciated. Thanks for your time!

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] setA = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] setB = {2,4,6,7,8};
    arrayProduct(setA, setB);
    System.out.print("The product is: " + int[] product);

}

public static int[] arrayProduct(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB){
    int[] product = {};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
        int num1 = arrayA[i];
        int num2 = arrayB[i];
        product += Integer.toString(num1 * num2) + " ";

    }
    return int[] product;

}
```

Comment: `product = arrayProduct(setA, setB)` might get you closer to the solution (instead of discarding the result)

Comment: You defined `product` as an int array, but you are trying to concatenate Strings to it. It's not clear if you want your output to be a String, an array of the products, or a single int (the sum of the products).

Comment: @eran i need it o be an array of the products, for example setA(1,2) setB(3,4) product(3,8) but i see what i did incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] setA = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int[] setB = {2,4,6,7,8};

    //Invoke the arrayProduct method which requires 2 int arrays int[] as parameters. Store the returned int[] in a new int[] called productArray.
    int[] productArray = arrayProduct(setA, setB);

    //Display the whole array on one line.
    System.out.print("The product is: " + Arrays.toString(productArray));

}

//If arrayProduct() is only accessed from within its own class, set the method to private. 
private static int[] arrayProduct(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB){

    //You could do some validation here before creating a product[] array to ensure both arrays are of the same length, if arrayA.length = 7 and arrayB.length = 6
    //you will get a IndexOutOfBoundsException... when trying to get the product of arrayA[6] * arrayB[6].
    int[] product = new int[arrayA.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
        product[i] = arrayA[i] * arrayB[i];

    }

    return product;

}
```

If you are new to Arrays in java check out the following link to gain a basic understanding https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp

Comment: I keep receiving the error "cannot find symbol" in Arrays.toString(productArray)) i understand you're converting an array type into a string so that it is printable, but i keep getting the error. thanks for your help regardless @bradley

Comment: import java.util.Arrays; into your java class.